# How is the Unreal rendering pipeline implimented?

Tags: rendering, unreal-4

I know this seems like a very broad question, but i am just interested in getting to know how the Unreal engine's rendering pipeline looks like, specially how it handles meterials, different types of lighting, and post processing. I know that Unreal4 uses differred shading, but how does it handle things like translucency, reflections, etc. I do not have access to the source code, that's why I asked this question here. You could even direct me to the source of the rendering part if available.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how a particular game engine implements a feature.